# PHP confused with the function

Tags: php

I don't know what happens with my PHP code.

I have table like this (t_balance)

```
badge_id | emp_name | month  | amount | balance_type
115201   | Greg     | August | 150000 | Tabungan Wajib
115201   | Greg     | August | 50000  | Tabungan Tambahan
115201   | Greg     | August | 75000  | Tabungan Tambahan
```

Now I want to lock for Tabungan Wajib just can submit 1 time, for Tabungan Tambahan can submit more than 1 time.

I use PHP in my code like this :

```
$cek_saldo = mysql_query("SELECT badge_id, month, balance_type FROM t_balance WHERE (balance_type='Tabungan Wajib' && badge_id='$badge_id' && month='August')") OR die(mysql_error());;
$found=mysql_num_rows($cek_saldo);
if($found > 0)
{
echo "Duplicate";
}
else
    {
    do submit data
}
```

I don't know what happen with my code. So if first time I submit for tabungan wajib, it saved. But if I want to submit more than 1time Tabungan Tambahan, it always said Duplicate.

Comment: it will say duplicate because there is already one from Wajib on your database. you need to check only when is Wajib submiting, or else after he submit once will always say duplicate even if its someone else submiting.

Answer (score 1):

> execute the query only if balance_type in your data you are submitting == Tabungan Wajib

Comment: if ($balance_type == 'Tabungan Wajib') { exit('you cannot do that');}

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `SELECT badge_id, month, balance_type FROM t_balance WHERE (balance_type='Tabungan Wajib')` so as long as `Tabungan Wajib` exists in the database you will never be able to submit any data, no matter what it contains. You should only execute that query if the `balance_type` equals `Tabungan Wajib`.

```
if ($balance_type == "Tabungan Wajib") {
   $cek_saldo = mysql_query("SELECT badge_id, month, balance_type FROM t_balance WHERE (balance_type='Tabungan Wajib' && badge_id='$badge_id' && month='August')") OR die(mysql_error());
   $limit = mysql_num_rows($cek_saldo);
} else {
   $limit = false;
}

if($limit)
{
   echo "Duplicate";
} else {
   // do submit data
}
```

Comment: @NoReply How are you setting `$balance_type`? You need to make sure `$balance_type` is set to the balance type of the submitted data, not just `"Tabungan Wajib"`. You only want to search for `"Tabungan Wajib"` if the submitted data contains it. e.g. `$balance_type = "Tabungan Tamahan"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of what you're trying to achieve, but this line of code

```
$found=mysql_num_rows($cek_saldo);
```

gives you the *number of rows* for your query result, which is most of the times more than zero rows. And you check in the `if statement` if it's larger than zero, which is the case in this code. So the `echo "Duplicate";` line runs successfully.

You need to check for a different variable for your `if clause`, depending on what you're exactly trying to do.